# How to display the camera screen inside html div in ionic 2

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, ionic2

I want to display the camera screen inside ion-content.

I have tried cordova-plugin-camera-preview. It shows some error

```
 startCamera(){
  // let react = {x: 40, y: 100, width: this.calcWidth ,height: 220}   //Decrepted due to previous code
    CameraPreview.startCamera({x: 40, y: 100, width: this.calcWidth, height: 220, toBack: false, previewDrag: true, tapPhoto: true});
        //.startCamera(react, defaultCamera:'back',tapEnabled: true, dragEnabled: true, toBack:true, alpha:1);  //Deprecated        
 }
```

I need to implement this concept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error that you see?

Comment: There is no action takes place when i click this function